# DateTime values fail in WCF query request

Tags: c#, wcf, datetime, wcf-data-services

While trying to query an OData sevice through WCF Data Services I ended up with invalid values in the request for my DateTime fields.

Here's the code:

```
var query = context.ApplicationData.Where(ad => 
            ad.dateFrom == DateTime.MinValue &&
            ad.dateTo == DateTime.MaxValue);
DataServiceCollection<ApplicationData> data = new DataServiceCollection<ApplicationData>(context);
data.LoadAsync(query);
```

Here's what I get:

```
[MyODataService]/ApplicationData()?$filter=dateFrom%20eq%20datetime'0001-01-01T00%3A00%3A00'%20and%20dateTo%20eq%20datetime'9999-12-31T23%3A59%3A59.9999999'
```

instead of

```
dateFrom=datetime'0001-01-01T00:00:00',dateTo=datetime'9999-12-31T23:59:59'
```

The request fails. Anyone have any idea why this escaping occurs for the DateTime values?

Comment: Use string instead of Datetime object

Comment: The model classes are auto-generated through the service reference, I'd rather not touch them...